Running Ubuntu on VMWare Fusion on MAC M1
I am trying to install Ubuntu as a Linux OS on my MAC M1 and read that trying to do this via a Virtual machine is the best way. Thus I installed the personal version of VMWare Fusion, which is free. Now Does this constellation cause any problems?
When I try to run the Virtual machine it gives me the error message: This virtual machine cannot be powered on because it requires the X86 machine architecture, which is incompatible with this Arm machine architectuure host. (See KB-84273).
Is there a easy work around?
And does this affect my ability to use the linux OS parallel to the Apple OS preinstalled?
This is my main goal. As well as free and via open source.

Of course you are trying to use an ARM version of Ubuntu?

This question is similar to: Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a Apple Silicon (M1) macOS Host?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
